# Calculate $ \int_{-2}^{0} \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

$ \int_{-2}^{0} \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}} dx $ = -$ 
2.887270... $

The function has no antiderivate and there's no symmetry here to help, if you solve this I would be thankful if you would for a highschooler ^^

Comment: So where did you find this integral and why to you want to study it? It looks a bit unnatural and just as something one would compose if one would like to have something "hard" to calculate. You already have a pretty good numerical value...

Comment: I just placed it on integral calculator to get the approximation. I found this exercise in a mathbook for admission test and I was just courious if there is a proper way to solve this :s

Comment: If you use the methods of Simpson or Trapeze, to approximate the value of the definite integral, you can check the Numerical Analysis Book of Richard Burden

Comment: $\int_{-2}^0 \frac{x}{\sqrt{\exp (x)+(x+2)^2}} \, dx=-6 \ln (\phi )=-6 \ln \left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)\right)$ Put value in: https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc

Comment: I guess substitution $t = (x+2)e^\frac{-x}{2}$ will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a tricky one!
$$\mathcal{J}=\int_{-2}^{0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}\,dx=\int_{-2}^{0}\frac{x e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{1+\left[(x+2)e^{-x/2}\right]^2}}\,dx  $$
and you may notice that up to a multiplicative constant the numerator $xe^{-x/2}$ is the derivative of $(x+2) e^{-x/2}$. Additionally the function $(x+2)e^{-x/2}$ is increasing on $(-2,0)$, going from $0$ to $2$.
By substituting $(x+2)e^{-x/2}=z$ we get
$$ \mathcal{J}= -2\int_{0}^{2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} = -2\,\text{arcsinh}(2) =-6\log\varphi$$
as claimed in the comments. As a *folklore* note , my (pretty old) version of Mathematica is unable to recognize such closed form for $\mathcal{J}$. A point for *humans vs machines*, I guess.