# Calculate$\int\limits_{-2}^{0} \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Calculate $$\int\limits_{-2}^{0} \frac{x}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}}dx$$

First I tried the substitution $t=x+2$ and obtained $$\int\limits_{0}^{2} \frac{t-2}{\sqrt{e^{t-2}+t^2}}dt$$ and than I thought to write it as $$\int\limits_{0}^{2} (t-2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{t-2}+t^2}}dt$$ and use the fact that $$2(\sqrt{e^{t-2}+t^2})'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{t-2}+t^2}} \cdot(e^{t-2}+2t)$$ Using integration by parts we get that we have to calculate (excluding some terms we know) $$\int\limits_{0}^{2} \sqrt{e^{t-2}+t^2}\cdot \frac{6e^{t-2}-2te^{t-2}+8}{(e^{t-2}+2t)^2}dt$$ which is uglier then the initial problem. Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Wolframalpha's calculation: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%2Fsqrt(e%5Ex%2B(x%2B2)%5E2)+from+-2+to+0
However, is it possible to find the closed form of the given integral?

Comment: Did you find this integral in a book? Perhaps previous problems or the topic of the chapter can give some clue. Note also that it is a definite integral, and that finding a primitive may not be the best way to compute it.

Comment: It was also answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2809087/515527 and here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2699140/515527

Comment: @Zacky  oh I had no idea :)) thanks

Comment: @Zacky  Thank you, i will use it next time

Comment: @Zacky I agree with you about the duplicate comment but with your comment it's not possible to figure out which one is the original one which is why that "possible duplicate" comment is there to show which is original and to indicate that the post has been flagged. Also, the comment was automatically added after I flagged it. I also flagged another link that you mentioned as "possible duplicate". My comment would automatically be deleted after this post is closed. That is how it works.

Comment: @Zacky  So from next time if you find a duplicate just flag it as duplicate and a comment of "possible duplicate" will be added for others as an indicator that the post has been flagged. No need to manually put the link in the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $y = (x+2)e^{-x/2}.$ You should get $I=-2\sinh^{-1}{2}$.

---

$\displaystyle y = (x+2)e^{-x/2}  \implies dy = -\frac{x}{2}e^{-x/2}\,dx$
and $\displaystyle \frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}} = \frac{xe^{-x/2}\,dx}{\sqrt{1+(x+2)^2e^{-x}}} = \frac{-2\,dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}.$

Therefore we have  $\displaystyle I = \int_{-2}^{0}\frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{e^x+(x+2)^2}} = -2\int_{0}^{2}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} = -2\sinh^{-1}(2)$, as claimed.

Comment: Welcome to the site ! This is a beautiful result, for sure ! I think it would be worth to elaborate.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I've added the details now, thanks!

Comment: Nice approach, $+1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Long method**
One possible method is the following. Using 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \, \frac{(-1)^n \, x^n}{4^n} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}} \\
\gamma(s,x) &= \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t} \, t^{s-1} \, dt
\end{align}
then:
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{-2}^{0} \frac{x \, dx}{\sqrt{e^{x} + (x+2)^{2}}} \\
&= \int_{-2}^{0} \frac{x \, e^{-x/2} \, dx}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{(x+2)^2}{e^{x}}\right)}} \\
&= \sum_{n} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{4^{n}} \, \int_{-2}^{0} e^{-(n+1/2) x} \, x \, (x+2)^{2n} \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{4^n} \, e^{2n+1} \, \int_{0}^{2} e^{-(n+1/2) t} \, (t-2) \, t^{2n} \, dt   \hspace{5mm} t \to x + 2 \\
&= \sum_{n} \binom{2n}{n} \, \frac{(-1)^{n}}{4^{n}} \, e^{2n+1} \, \left[ \left(\frac{2}{2n+1}\right)^{2n+2} \, \gamma(2n+2, 2n+1) - 2 \, \left(\frac{2}{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1} \, \gamma(2n+1, 2n+1) \right]   \\
&= 4 \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \, \frac{(-1)^{n} \, e^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^{2n+2}} \, \left[ \gamma(2n+2, 2n+1) - (2n+1) \, \gamma(2n+1, 2n+1) \right] \\
&= - 4 \, \sum_{n} \binom{2n}{n} \, \frac{(-1)^{n} \, e^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^{2n+2}} \, (2n+1)^{2n+1} \, e^{-(2n+1)} \\
&= -4 \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \, \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)} \\
&= - \, \sum_{n} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{4^{n}} \, \int_{0}^{2} y^{2n} \, dy \\
&= -2 \, \int_{0}^{2} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} \\ 
&= -2 \, \sinh^{-1}(2).
\end{align}

**Short method**

\begin{align}
I &= \int_{-2}^{0} \frac{x \, dx}{\sqrt{e^{x} + (x+2)^{2}}} \\
&= -2 \int_{-2}^{0} \frac{- (x/2) \, e^{-x/2} \, dx}{\sqrt{1 + ((x+2) \, e^{-x/2})^2}} \\
\end{align}
Let $u = (x+2) \, e^{-x/2}$, $du = -(x/2) \, e^{-x/2} \, dx$, then
\begin{align}
I &= -2 \int_{-2}^{0} \frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u^2}} = -2 \left[\sinh^{-1}(u)\right]_{-2}^{0} \\
&= -2 \, \sinh^{-1}(2).
\end{align}

It is of interest to note that
$$\int_{-2}^{\infty} \frac{x \, dx}{\sqrt{e^{x} + (x+2)^{2}}} = 0.$$

Comment: Are you sure that  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \, \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)}$ does converge ?